# How can I simulate inheriting from a generic parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

That actually inheriting from a generic parameter cannot be done has been covered on SO many times already.  My question is, practically, how can a similar effect be achieved?  Use case:

```
public interface ILotsOfMethods
{ 
    // Lots of methods go here
}

public class LotsOfMethods<T> : T, ILotsOfMethods
{
    public Func<string, bool> Method1Delegate { get; set; }
    public Func<string, bool> Method2Delegate { get; set; }
    // ...
    public Func<string, bool> MethodNDelegate { get; set; }

    public bool ILotsOfMethods.Method1(string str)
    {
        if (this.Method1Delegate != null)
        {
            return this.Method1Delegate(str);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // the other methods all follow this pattern
}

public class LotsOfMethodsList : List<ILotsOfMethods>, ILotsOfMethods
{
    public bool ILotsOfMethods.Method1(string str)
    {
        foreach (var handler in this)
        {
            try
            {
                return handler.Method1(str); // even if defined, this COULD throw NotImplementedException if it decides it's not interested in str
            }
            catch(NotImplementedException)
            { }
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // the other methods all follow this pattern
}
```

With this setup, I can easily implement only a subset of methods that I'm interested in by writing:

```
public class MethodAwareClient : ThirdPartyClient, ILotsOfMethods
{
    // concrete implementations of ILotsOfMethods as default handlers

    public void override Exec(Query query)
    {
        Log.Trace("Executing!");  // could be something more meaningful
        base.Exec(query); // third party code
    }

    public void override QueryComplete(Query query)
    {
        LotsOfMethodsList handlers;
        handlers.Add(this);
        handlers.Add(query as ILotsOfMethods); //null checking ommitted for brevity

        if (handlers.Method1("needsApproval"))
        {
            throw new BigBadException(); // Don't judge the logic of throwing after the query completes too harshly...simply for example!
        }
    }
}

public void Foo()
{
    Query normalQuery;
    LotsOfMethods<Query> scaryQuery;
    scaryQuery.Method1Handler = (string str) => { return true; };

    MethodAwareClient mac;
    mac.Exec(normalQuery);
    mac.Exec(scaryQuery); // this should throw
}
```

The general goal is to allow any object of any type to easily override specific tasks on a per-instance basis without having to generate a potentially large implementation for `ILotsOfMethods` for each class that wants to implement some of the functionality.

A more concrete example: Imagine a class `MySqlClient`, which implements base handlers for `IQueryApproval` and inherits from a 3rd party `SqlClient`. This interface would have `IQueryApproval.NeedsApproval(Query)` and `IQueryApproval.GetApprovers(Query)`. The default might be that updates require approval, and selects don't.  But if I am writing a query that I deem is dangerous (either from a PII standpoint or performance), maybe I want to override this behavior.  So I pass in a `QueryApproval<Query>` to the MySqlClient, which is passed around in various ways by the `SqlClient`.  By inheriting from the Query, even if `MySqlClient` overrides a method `CanRunQuery(Query query)`, we can maintain context information about the Query while keeping the underlying interface defined by `SqlClient`.

I can see how to do this by breaking `IQueryApproval` into `INeedsApproval` and `IGetApprovers`, and implementing the delegate wrapper for each.  I can also see how to do this by fully implementing `ILotsOfMethods` in each derived class, but both of these seem a bit on the clunky side.  I'll admit my above is a bit of overhead as well, but if implemented users of the interface would have their code simplified, which is really the goal.

Comment: So, your question is, what code/design can you use to achieve more or less the same benefits as the non-compiling example code?

Comment: Aside from the pros/cons of the design, have you considered something like the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)? Have `Method1` through `MethodN` defined on a base non-implemented `ILotsOfMethods` component (each throwing `NotImplementedException`), define a common `abstract` base that implements those methods as `virtual` and by default calls the wrapped `ILotsOfMethods` instance corresponding method. Each concrete implementation `MethodAwareClient` class `override` the methods they implement.

Comment: Sounds similar to setting up a mock object (e.g. in [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart))

Comment: The problem with Decorator is that (referring to my latter example) `SqlClient` may not have an `IQuery` that is implemented by `Query`. Since this theoretical library is 3rd party code, I wouldn't be able to change the implementation myself. There's no getting around the need to actually subclass `Query`; the question is how best to go about it.

Comment: @Rollie: Well, if you're willing to re-implement `ILotsOfMethods`, you can pass in the wrapped object you're decorating, then implement each method to call that wrapped object's equivalent method.

Comment: If I understand correctly (and I may not), that means implementing the full `ILotsOfMethods` for each type that wants to use it, which is what I'm trying to avoid. It would alleviate the need for the delegate-to-interface-method forwarding logic, which could be factored out to a common bit of code, so maybe a step in the right direction.

Comment: @Rollie Considering that you are looking to avoid implementing ILotsOfMethods repeatedly for each type, you might want to consider using DynamicProxy to create mixins.  I've posted an answer below regarding that approach.  I wrote the sample code in-line, so you may need to tweak it in order to get it to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to be able to add functionality to previously defined classes.

Try using Castle.DynamicProxy2 to create mixins.  Here is a link to a write up about doing that http://kozmic.net/2009/08/12/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-xiii-mix-in-this-mix/

The general idea is similar to creating a decorator, except without having to create the forwarding methods your self.

Presumably, based on the tutorial you would do something like this:

```
public static TBaseType CreateMixin<TBaseType, TAddon>(Func<TAddon> constructAddon) where TBaseType : class where TAddon : class
{
    var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
    var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions();
    options.AddMixinInstance(constructAddon());
    return (TBaseType)generator.CreateClassProxy(typeof(TBaseType), new Type[]{typeof(TAddon)}, options);
}
```

What this method returns is actually a subclass of `TBaseType` that also implements `TAddon` and then forwards the calls for that interface to the instance created in the `constructAddon` factory method.

Call it like this:

```
public void Foo()
{
    Form normalForm = CreateMixin<Form, ILotsOfMethods>(()=>new LotsOfMethods());
    ILotsOfMethods wrappedForm = (ILotsOfMethods) normalForm;
    wrappedForm.Method1Handler = (string str) => { return true; };

    Database normalDatabase = CreateMixin<Database, ILotsOfMethods>(()=>new LotsOfMethods());
    ILotsOfMethods wrappedDatabase = (ILotsOfMethods) normalDatabase;
    wrappedDatabase.Method3Handler = (string str) => { return false; };

    MethodAwareClient mac;
    mac.ProcessForm(wrappedForm);
    mac.ProcessDatabase(wrappedDatabase);
}
```

Note that this will only add on to non-sealed classes.  There are other options provided by the library though, and you could still work with sealed classes, if they implement an interface that you could work with.  Then you could create a proxy that implements the target class's primary interface and the add-on interface, and the proxy would forward calls to an instance of the target class for the primary interface and an instance of the add-on class for the add-on methods.

Here is a [link(http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2010/08/12/type-safe-dynamic-mixins/)](http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2010/08/12/type-safe-dynamic-mixins/) showing mixing three classes based on the interfaces that they implement, merged into a composite interface.  Note that with this technique you can merge multiple interfaces, which may allow you to break down `ILotsOfMethods` into multiple `IAFewRelatedMethod` interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suspect this could be a case of [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If it is, perhaps include a more complete context of what you are attempting to do. Assuming it's not, then...

Secondly, I have concerns about the use of a large `ILotsOfMethods`; this is likely a violator of the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and perhaps a root cause of your headaches. I think this should be your first avenue of consideration to redesign. Assuming that this interface design is fixed/best for you, then...

Based on your comments, perhaps this is a viable design based on the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

First, you define your base interface and decorator:

```
public interface ILotsOfMethods
{ 
    // Lots of methods go here
    bool Method1(string arg);
    bool Method2(string arg);
    TimeSpan Method6(string arg);
}

public abstract class LotsOfMethodsDecorator : ILotsOfMethods
{
    private readonly ILotsOfMethods LotsOfMethodsToBeDecorated;

    protected LotsOfMethodsDecorator(ILotsOfMethods lotsOfMethods)
    {
        this.LotsOfMethodsToBeDecorated = lotsOfMethods;
    }

    public virtual bool Method1(string arg)
    {
        return LotsOfMethodsToBeDecorated.Method1(arg);
    }

    public virtual bool Method2(string arg)
    {
        return LotsOfMethodsToBeDecorated.Method2(arg);
    }

    public virtual TimeSpan Method6(string arg)
    {
        return LotsOfMethodsToBeDecorated.Method6(arg);
    }
}
```

Then a common terminating point which would throw a `NotImplementedException` for each method:

```
public class LotsOfMethodsNotImplemented : ILotsOfMethods
{
    public bool Method1(string arg)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Method2(string arg)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TimeSpan Method6(string arg)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Method-aware clients can now simply override the methods they know how to implement:

```
public class Method1Client : LotsOfMethodsDecorator
{
    public Method1Client(ILotsOfMethods lotsOfMethods)
        : base(lotsOfMethods)
    {

    }

    public override bool Method1(string arg)
    {
        return  arg == "shouldContinue";
    }
}
```

Third-party components that cannot inherit from the base decorator should be wrapped with a basic decorator and can perform third-party specific code:

```
public class Some3rdPartQueryWrapper : LotsOfMethodsDecorator
{
    private readonly Some3rdPartyQuery Query;

    public Some3rdPartQueryWrapper(Some3rdPartyQuery query, ILotsOfMethods lotsOfMethods)
        : base(lotsOfMethods)
    {
        this.Query = query;
    }

    public override bool Method2(string arg)
    {
        if (this.Query.MaybeSomeThirdPartyValidation())
            return false;
        else
            return this.Query.SomeThirdPartyMethod2(arg);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm a bit confused with your high-level "MethodAwareClient" you have implementing your `ILotsOfMethods`. I'm going to assume this is also a decorator for the purposes of this answer, but you can easily change this to simply wrap the decorator or ideally just an `ILotsOfMethods` instance:

```
public class MethodAwareClient : LotsOfMethodsDecorator
{
    public MethodAwareClient(ILotsOfMethods lotsOfMethods)
        : base(lotsOfMethods)
    {

    }

    public void HandleForm()
    {
        if (Method1("shouldContinue"))
        {
            //...
        }

        if (Method2("needSleep"))
        {
            Task.Delay(Method6("sleepTime"));
        }
    }
}
```

Wiring it all together:

```
var some3rdPartyQuery = new Some3rdPartyQuery();

var client = 
    new MethodAwareClient(
    new Some3rdPartQueryWrapper(some3rdPartyQuery, 
    new Method1Client(
    new LotsOfMethodsNotImplemented()
    )));

client.HandleForm();
```

It can get hairy with the nesting, but some API tweaks can workaround that.

Again, I suspect this isn't the *ideal* solution to the *concrete* issue you're facing. I strongly suggest you consider my initial two concerns (XY Problem and Interface Segregation Principle) first.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the context being passed around the internals of the 3rd party will be lost.  See updates to `MethodAwareClient`  and `Foo` for illustration.

Comment: @Rollie: Then provide `MethodAwareClient : ThirdPartyClient` class a reference to your `ILotsOfMethods` decorated object then? Why does `MethodAwareClient` need to implement `ILotsOfMethods`?

Comment: `MethodAwareClient` actually does not need to implement `ILotsOfMethods` at all. I can provide `MethodAwareClient` a reference to an unrelated `ILotsOfMethods` implementation, but what I'm looking for is one on a *per query* basis.  Look at my updated sample code in the original post: `QueryComplete` will be called twice, once for the `normalQuery`, once for the `scaryQuery`. How does the logic in `QueryComplete` know which is which? One of them needs additional logic based on the specific query, whereas one does not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this.
I had an assembly that I couldn't count on being available at runtime, but if it was present, I wanted to be able to use objects in it.

The problem was that I wasn't allowed to refer to the assembly from within my own.

Let's say that the object I wanted was something like this:

```
public class RunTimeClass {
    public RunTimeClass () { }
    public void DoSomethingCool() { /*...*/ }
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

What I did was define an interface that matched this class:

```
public class ICompileTime {
   void DoSomethingCool();
   string SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

Then I wrote some code that given the interface or an abstract class, an assembly and the name of a class would dynamically write a new class that implements the interface and reroutes all the methods to the target class in the assembly. Effectively, this made a dynamic adapter onto `RunTimeClass`.

Usage:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("DoNothing");
Type t = asm.GetType("DoNothing.Nothing");

AdapterCompiler compiler = new AdapterCompiler();
AdapterFactory<NothingAdapter> factory = compiler.DefineAdapter<NothingAdapter>(t);

NothingAdapter adapter = factory.Construct(new object[] { "dave" });

int sum = adapter.Sum(1, 2, 3);
```

I'm going to go ahead and put the whole shebang here - it's long, but not super long. First, the AdapterCompiler:

```
public class AdapterCompiler
{
    public AdapterFactory<T> DefineAdapter<T>(Type targetType)
    {
        return DefineAdapter<T>(targetType, null);
    }

    public AdapterFactory<T> DefineAdapter<T>(Type targetType, string outputFile)
    {
        Type abstractType = typeof(T);
        AssemblyBuilder ab = null;

        // Get the TypeBuilder for the new class
        TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder(abstractType, out ab, outputFile);

        // Make a field for the target type within the new class
        FieldBuilder fb = DefineTargetObjectField(tb, targetType);

        // Map the abstract methods onto the target type
        DefineAbstractMethods(tb, fb, abstractType, targetType);

        // make a constructor that can vector out to the target type
        DefineConstructor(tb, fb, abstractType, targetType);

        // build the class
        Type adaptedType = tb.CreateType();

        if (outputFile != null)
            ab.Save(outputFile);

        // Make a factory object for building the class
        return new AdapterFactory<T>(adaptedType, targetType);
    }

    private string GetTargetObjectFieldName(Type targetType)
    {
        // create a consistent name mangled field name
        return "_f" + targetType.Name;
    }

    private FieldBuilder DefineTargetObjectField(TypeBuilder tb, Type targetType)
    {
        // Define the actual field
        return tb.DefineField(GetTargetObjectFieldName(targetType), targetType, FieldAttributes.Private);
    }

    private TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder(Type abstractType, out AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder, string outputFile)
    {
        // make an assembly builder, module builder and type builder.
        // we only need the AssemblyBuilder and TypeBuilder
        AssemblyName assemName = new AssemblyName("Assembly" + abstractType.Name);
        assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemName,
            outputFile != null ? AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave : AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder mb = outputFile != null ?
            assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemName.Name, outputFile) :
            assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemName.Name);
        TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("Wrapped"+abstractType.Name, abstractType.Attributes & ~(TypeAttributes.Abstract), abstractType);
        return tb;
    }

    private void DefineAbstractMethods(TypeBuilder tb, FieldBuilder fb, Type abstractType, Type targetType)
    {
        // we need to pass along a list of already defined fields
        List<string> definedProperties = new List<string>();

        // get the abstract methods - tricky - use a lambda expression to filter via LINQ
        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methods = abstractType.GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.IsAbstract);

        foreach (MethodInfo mi in methods)
        {
            DefineAbstractMethod(tb, fb, mi, targetType, definedProperties);
        }
    }

    private Type[] GetParameterTypes(MethodInfo mi)
    {
        // given a method, get a list of the types of its parameters
        ParameterInfo[] pi = mi.GetParameters();
        Type[] types = new Type[pi.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pi.Length; i++)
        {
            types[i] = pi[i].ParameterType;
        }
        return types;
    }

    private Type[] GetParameterTypes(PropertyInfo propi)
    {
        // given a property, get a list of the types of its parameters
        ParameterInfo[] pi = propi.GetIndexParameters();
        Type[] types = new Type[pi.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pi.Length; i++)
        {
            types[i] = pi[i].ParameterType;
        }
        return types;
    }


    private void VerifyParameterMatch(string methodName, Type[] source, Type[] dest)
    {
        // type match parameters for one method to another
        if (source.Length != dest.Length)
        {
            throw new Exception("In method " + methodName + ", parameter list length for wrapper and target object differ.");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            if (source[i] != dest[i])
            {
                throw new Exception("In method " + methodName + ", expected parameter " + i + " to be type " + dest[i].Name + ", but found " +
                    source[i].Name + ".");
            }
        }
    }

    private void DefineAbstractMethod(TypeBuilder tb, FieldBuilder fb, MethodInfo mi, Type targetType, List<string> definedProperties)
    {
        // map the abstract method from one class into the concrete implementation in another

        Type[] parameterTypes = GetParameterTypes(mi);

        // get the target method
        MethodInfo targetMethod = targetType.GetMethod(mi.Name, parameterTypes);

        if (targetMethod == null)
            throw new Exception("Unable to find matching method for " + mi.Name + " in class " + targetType.Name);

        // get the target method's parameter types
        Type[] targetParameterTypes = GetParameterTypes(targetMethod);

        // Ensure that they match, throw on failure
        VerifyParameterMatch(mi.Name, parameterTypes, targetParameterTypes);

        MethodAttributes attrs = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot;
        // IsSpecialName is equivalent to "implementation of a property"
        if (mi.IsSpecialName)
        {
            attrs = attrs | MethodAttributes.SpecialName;
            // we only really handle get_/set_ properties
            if (mi.Name.StartsWith("get_") || mi.Name.StartsWith("set_"))
            {
                string propName = mi.Name.Substring(4);
                if (!definedProperties.Contains(propName))
                {
                    definedProperties.Add(propName);
                    PropertyInfo pi = mi.DeclaringType.GetProperty(propName);
                    tb.DefineProperty(propName, pi.Attributes, pi.PropertyType, GetParameterTypes(pi));
                }
            }
        }

        // define the method
        MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod(mi.Name, attrs, mi.ReturnType, parameterTypes);

        ILGenerator gen = mb.GetILGenerator();
        // fetch the target object
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fb);

        // pass all of our parameters on
        for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i + 1);
        }

        // call the method, virtually or otherwise
        gen.Emit(targetMethod.IsVirtual ? OpCodes.Callvirt : OpCodes.Call, targetMethod);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }

    private void DefineConstructor(TypeBuilder tb, FieldBuilder fb, Type abstractType, Type targetType)
    {
        // define a construct of the form:
        // .ctor(Type targetObjectType, Type[] constructorArgumentTypes, object[] constructorArguments)
        //
        // This implementation is effectively:
        // ConstructorInfo ci = targetObjectType.GetConstructor(constructorArgumentTypes)
        // _ftargetType = ci.Invoke(constructorArguments)
        //

        ConstructorBuilder cb = tb.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public,
            CallingConventions.Standard,
            new Type[] { typeof(Type), typeof(Type[]), typeof(object[]) });
        ILGenerator gen = cb.GetILGenerator();

        // see if there is a default constructor in the abstract type
        ConstructorInfo ci = abstractType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (ci == null)
        {
            // if not, get Object contructor
            Type objectType = typeof(object);
            ci = objectType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        }
        // call base class constructor
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ci);

        // needed later
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

        // get the constructor from targetObjectType
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2); 
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetConstructor", new Type[] { typeof(Type[]) });
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, mi);

        // stack is now:
        // 0: this
        // 1: constuctor info

        // invoke the constructor on the arguments
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_3);
        mi = typeof(ConstructorInfo).GetMethod("Invoke", new Type[] { typeof(object[]) });

        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, mi);

        // store into _ftargetType
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fb);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }
}
```

Next the AdapterFactory:

```
// An AdapterFactory is a class that given a type T, will construct a derived class (generated by AdapterCompiler)
// and call its constructor
//
public class AdapterFactory<T>
{
    private Type _adaptedType, _targetType;

    public AdapterFactory(Type adaptedType, Type targetType)
    {
        _adaptedType = adaptedType;
        _targetType = targetType;
    }

    public T Construct(object[] arguments)
    {
        // get the constructor
        ConstructorInfo ci = _adaptedType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(Type), typeof(Type[]), typeof(object[]) });

        // invoke it
        Type[] argTypes = GetArgTypes(arguments);
        return (T)ci.Invoke(new object[] { _targetType, argTypes, arguments });
    }

    private Type[] GetArgTypes(object[] objs)
    {
        Type[] types = new Type[objs.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
        {
            types[i] = objs[i].GetType();
        }
        return types;
    }
}
```